# How to show the error on a web page if an AJAX call fails (e.g. Timeout error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I have to display an error on a requested page if an AJAX call fails to reach the server.

I don't know the exact Ajax code for doing this.

The code I've tried so far is:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       url: '/tasks',
       timeout: (5000),
       success: function(){
          alert('success'); 
       },
       error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError){
          abort("Error! Type: " +strError);
       }
});
```

When I kill the server (after the page itself is loaded!) this AJAX call should display an error message, and when the server is restarted then it should respond properly to the request.

Comment: You mean, you stop the server, it should throw an error, then you start the server again and it shows a success message, without triggering the call again? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: To add to what Felix said, the AJAX request is going to a location on the same site, therefore if the server is stopped the website wouldn't be visible anyway? Please correct me if I've misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: there may be trggering, i just want to send error msg to requested page in case of server unavailable

Comment: You have to write your own retry the server method, if original request fails because Jquery don't provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Just my theoretical guess, you can do it by setTimeout function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout( ajaxPoll, 5000);
});

function ajaxPoll(){
  $.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       url: '/tasks',
       success: function(){
          $('alertWindow').hide(); 
       },
       error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError){
          $('alertWindow').show();
       }
  });
}
```

Also it means that you can't use modal window **alert**, it should be only DOM element.